# Failed to execute tools\android.bat: solution

Tags: android

When I try to open up the SDK Manager in eclipse it says opening shortly, but never opens. I've tried to open the exe file but it displays an error message saying:

> Failed to execute tools\android:bat the system cannot find the file specified

My path environment variable leads it to the tools folder.

This is the path:

```
C:\Users\Shan\Documents\Computer Science - YEAR 2\Android App Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\tools
```

Comment: Try a path without a space in it... that's a common issue.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately that didn't solve it :(

Comment: I think sdk has been destroyed. Need correct sdk and next time need close eclipse, studio, antivirus or other programms when update.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In my case the **Tools** **directory** **just** **disappear**.

..\sdk\tools

**To solve it:**

1) Just go to SDK zip -> adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip

2) Unzip the Tools Directory only.

3) copy it under ../sdk/

Comment: ditto here.  this fixed it.  +1

Comment: This happened to me too. I deleted some packages with SDK Manager and it deleted tools library.

Comment: I don't understand, I've installed only the SDK command line tools, not the SDK itself it seems? I cannot access and sdk directory if I don't have it yet

Comment: thanks. I have downloaded the tool directory only at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip

Comment: @MinhNguyen just using your download link fixed everything ABSOLUTE LEGEND!

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem today. Press the Windows button and Search for android.bat(in the search programs and files text field)

Then copy the file to your android SDK folder (`C:\Users\Shan\Documents\Computer Science - YEAR 2\Android App Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\tools\`).

After that don't run SDK manager but run the `android.bat` file.

Hope this helps

-Zaniar

Comment: For me, I already had the android.bat file inside tools folder. Right click the android.bat file and give run as administrator, it will automatically open the Android SDK Manager, then it downloads file then give install, It installing fine for me.

Comment: Hey, I can't find an android.bat file...What do I do?

Answer (score 15):

I had to move the AVD manager from `/sdk/tools/lib` to the root folder `/sdk`

Comment: thanks. this worked for me as well. from the error message, it looks like it will try to look for android.bat in tools directory under current directory. so moving the application to sdk works.

Comment: This worked. Why the heck did they put it there then?

Answer (score 13):

Copy the `AVD Manager.exe` and `SDK Manager.exe` from

```
SDK_ROOT_FOLDER/tools/lib/
```

into

```
SDK_ROOT_FOLDER
```

Comment: you're the real hero

Answer (score 6):

I've been working with this problem for three days and finally was able to run SDK Manager by

==> Running the android.bat file *as administrator*

Note: I did not have to make any changes to the .bat file (such as setting the java_exe path) in order for the manager to run.

I saw this as a comment on the top answer but can't upvote yet, so confirming it here!

Answer (score 4):

I cancelled an update to Android Tools and it seems there's a bug with unzipping the old (or new?) version back into {android_sdk}/tools. The zip is located in {android_sdk}/temp. Just unzip it into the right location and it should work again.

Answer (score 3):

If the accepted answer doesn't help anyone, it also might be a permission issue (if the SDK is installed in `Program Files (x86)`, for example, so try running `android.bat` as Administrator,

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when updating the Android SDK Tools and SDK Platform-tools from the SDK Manager. I had to replace the **tools** folder with one located in a zip folder inside the **temp** folder.

Answer (score 2):

In My case, While I installed visual studio 2015, The SDK files were missed and I am getting an error window shown below.
[image]

So I manually downloaded the tools from the following URL.

[tools_r24.0.2-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r24.0.2-windows.zip)

Then extract the zip file and copy the tools folder in the following location.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think current Android SDK only works with JDK x86 version. I search so much but when installed JDK x86 version Android SDK manager worked without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your android.bat file to `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools` folder  or copy all files to `C:\`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this error, it may be an issue with your COMSPEC environment variable.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284746/3866013 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Caused it myself because while runing Android SDK Manager i hit UNINSTALL SDK Tools.

I fixed the issue by running the installation of the Android SDK again. The installation folder had to be the same as previously. After the installation, everything was back again as it was.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem on Windows 7:
I was going to update the SDK using Android SDK Manager but android.bat was not found because previously it uninstall the older one and then installs new. In my case my SDK Update was interrupted i.e. in other words, could not install after the SDK Manager uninstalled the tools, so my machine was not able to find android.bat. What I did was just downloaded the standalone SDK tools to the same folder where my SDK were from :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Answer (score 0):

```
https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other
```

Here are two options for downloading the Android SDK for Windows users. One in recommended option and the other is .zip file. Zip file worked well.
    Another option may also work. Try searching android.bat with windows search engine. If you find the one, copy it and paste in SDK tools folder.

Answer (score 0):

open Sdk Manager.exe, then i deleted first Android Sdk tools, so, I also appeared such a mistake, then I downloaded installer_r24.3.2-windows.exe, installing, copy C:\Users\Super Man\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools folder to my Sdk path,run My Sdk Path\android.bat ,ok!!

Answer (score 0):

I did the following :

1. I created a folder SDK right below my C-drive
2. I unzipped tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip to C:\SDK
3. I moved SDK Manager.exe from C:\SDK\tools\lib to C:\SDK
4. I first ran SDK Manager.exe in 'normal mode',but this gave me the error, but when I ran SDK Manager.exe as ADMINISTRATOR it didn't return the error.

Answer (score -2):

The reg command exists but for unknown reason my path variable was corrupted during some installation.

So some basic element were missing:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```