# Cannot install SDK for eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I can't install SDK and eclipse as well. While I am trying to install an error message is shown. I can not figure it out.

> [unable to execute tools\android.bat:, error 2
>   The system can not find the file specified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSNfp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. Press the **Windows** button and Search for **android.bat** (in the search programs and files text field)

Then copy the file to your android SDK folder (C:\Users\Shan\Documents\Computer Science - YEAR 2\Android App Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\tools).

After that don't run SDK manager but run the android.bat file.

Hope this helps

-Zaniar

from here : 
[Failed to execute tools\android.bat: solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015587/failed-to-execute-tools-android-bat-solution)

Comment: solved. Thank You @ Morteza Soleimani