# Failed to execute tools\android.bat

Tags: android, sdk, execute

I am very new in the android development,I download the SDK "installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe" form the android "https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i".
Initially i install it works fine,but due to some additional things I installed "jdk-8u25-windows-x64.exe". After JDK installation when i tried to run farther Android SDK "installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe" it shows me error "Failed to execute tools\android.bat".

I also checked many solutions on the stackoverflow like....
**"I just copied sdk manager.exe and avd manager.exe from ..sdk\tools\lib to ..sdk"** 
**"Change the line in the android.bat file with 'set java_exe= JAVA PATH\jre7\bin\java.exe'"**
But did not get any positive result.
I try after removing JDK and install only JRE and try Andriod SDK but even that it shows me same issue.
Don't say it's permission issue because i also execute SDK as administrator permission.

Please help me out with this issue.

I am using windows 7 platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to execute tools\android.bat: solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015587/failed-to-execute-tools-android-bat-solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer,

One additional path was added in the COMSPEC environment variable, there should be only 
 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" this line.

To check COMSPEC, type on the cmd
 **echo %COMSPEC%**