# Failed to execute android.bat even its exist

Tags: java, android, windows, batch-file

i've search from all question in stacoverflow, but i did not find my answer.
actually i want to run my SDK Manager. but it says "Failed to execute android.bat :The System cannot find the file specified." even the android.bat is exists.

then, i try to manually execute android.bat. but still get the same error thing.

> Windows cannot find 'C:\....\sdk\tools\android.bat'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

so i try to run in command prompt, i get this error:

```
./android.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./android.bat: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./android.bat: line 3: `rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project`
```

Can someone help me to fix this error?
PS i'm running in Windows 8, installed JAVA 64 bit.

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to execute tools\android.bat: solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015587/failed-to-execute-tools-android-bat-solution)

Comment: @JimLewis i already try that before, but still can't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved it by executing this command in the cmd of windows.
The git commands in gitbash and the others in the cmd
Hope it helps.