# android sdk manager initializing but not opening

Tags: java, android, eclipse

when I run android sdk manager ,a small window pops up in

eclipse : it says "initializing..SDK manager will show up shortly.

android studio : "starting sdk manager"
but nothing happens afterwards.

till now i have tried following solutions with no luck:

->changing android.bat to proper java/jre directory with/without quotes.

-> running as administrator

-> deleting the .android folder in c:users.

-> making sure that java directory is before windows/system32 directory.

all the above solutions haven't helped at all. the problem remains still the same.
i m using jdk 8. is it true that android doesn't run with jdk8 and requires jdk7?
because this leaves the  setting up java7 as the last option.

Answer (score 1):

Please run directly /tools/android.bat to check whether there is any error message. If you get a JDK not found error. Try the following, if not, forget it.

In general, when you set environment parameters, sdk should be in "PATH" "CLASSPATH", but one time, I have the same situation, when I ran an exe to reinstall JDK. I got an error to ask me to use JAVA_HOME if JDK already installed.

So add the JDK path in JAVA_HOME to have a try.

Comment: i have already tried the above solutions. i had already added JAVA_HOME as path. i dont get error like "jdk not found.". when i run avdmanager directly from lib folder of sdk i get error as "failed to execute tools\android.bat. the system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @shane Dont know whether it's late. So new problem now. For this problem check [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015587/failed-to-execute-tools-android-bat-solution) Hope you already solved this problem before seeing this!! (I understand well how you hate this kind of setting problem)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is now solved. I don't know why and how this worked but I did this:    earlier I was deleting the last 2 lines from following lines from the android.bat file and adding the required path. set java_exe= call lib\find_java.bat if not defined java_exe goto :EOF but later I commented these two lines using rem and added the path as before and it worked.. In both the cases I had modified the swt_path.