# Issues setting up Android Emulator in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.3

I have recently installed Android Studio 2.3.3 and Apache Cordova in order to construct cross-mobile apps. While the installation of Cordova and the main Android Studio IDE seems to have been a success, I have having issues setting up the Android Emulators.

I was unable to locate the AVD Manager.exe in the SDK folder, so I downloaded a new "AVD Manager.exe". However, when I try to open the executable I get the following message:

> Failed to execute tools\android.bat:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

When I do open up Android Studio I can now see the greyed AVD Manager icon, so I am not sure if I am on the right path to resolving my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to execute tools\android.bat: solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015587/failed-to-execute-tools-android-bat-solution)

Answer (score 0):

Built-in AVD is laggy and slow enough. Use Genymotion instead. It's free for personal usage.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is of minimum 8 GB ram , its OK to use AVD .or else I suggest you to use genymotion.  Its free and fastest . or else its better to build apps in a physical device.